# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'member_id' referenced before assignment in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I don't understand what im doing wrong here

```
@commands.command()
async def level(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    member_id = str(member_id)
    guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    
    user = await self.bot.pg_con.fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2", member_id, guild_id)
```

its giving me this error

```
UboundLocalError: local variable 'member_id' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Post your complete code or at-least one that can reproduce the error. Where else does your code define `member_id`?

Comment: In the first line of the method, you have `member` and in 2nd line you have used `member_id` on the right hand side. That is the error

Comment: Thanks @AjayA yeah its working now. I'm just blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you have posted on here, it seems that you are trying to use the variable `member_id` without having declared it. If member_id is not a global variable, it will have to be declared and assigned a value before it can be used or converted to a string. An example would be so:

```
@commands.command()
async def level(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    #Assuming member has the id
    member_id = member.id #declaring member_id here
    member_id = str(member_id)
    guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    
    user = await self.bot.pg_con.fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2", member_id, guild_id)
```